# Bazel build not respecting my git submodules

Tags: git, bazel, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm running a `bazel build` in a project that is composed of git submodules, 
with the following structure:

```
/work/
├── tensorflow/ [git submodule]
└── train/
    └── DeepSpeech/ [git submodule]
        └── native_client/
```

The build command looks like this:

```
bazel build \
    --config=monolithic \
    -c opt \
    --copt=-O3 \
    --copt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" \
    --copt=-fvisibility=hidden \
    //native_client:libdeepspeech.so \
    //native_client:generate_trie
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: /work/tensorflow/native_client/BUILD:6:1: Executing genrule //native_client:ds_git_version failed (Exit 1)
realpath: /work/train/DeepSpeech/native_client/../.git/: Not a directory
```

It seems to be complaining that `/work/train/DeepSpeech/.git` isn't a directory, and it would be correct because `/work/train/DeepSpeech/.git` is a file, containing the path to the the git tree of the git submodule.

Here are the contents of `/work/train/DeepSpeech/.git`:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/train/DeepSpeech
```

My question is: Is there a way to have bazel respect the submodule structure of my repository? Ideally, there would be some flags I could pass in my `bazel build` command that would make it magically work, but I'm open to other options.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent first question @mathematiguy - Good to see you're contributing to the community. I've proposed an edit for you, but for future posts, you can indent blocks of code using `ctrl + k`, or with 4 spaces, or with a tab. There's also a button in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Bazel indeed doesn't understand Git submodules.

Bazel however has a notion of repositories, and you can specify the structure of your repositories in the `WORKSPACE` file that's in the root of your workspace, using so-called repository rules.

[This page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html) explains the concept of the `WORKSPACE` file, and I believe [this is the rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#git_repository) you'll need.

Comment: The article moved to [`git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/git.html#git_repository).